# Problem with snake ticks in pgfplots for bell shaped normal distribution

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to draw two sided created region for normal distribution (see figure below). I have issue with snake ticks proper alignment and area looks suspicious to me. Am I missing something here? Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks 
[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,backgrounds,snakes}
\begin{document}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{3}{%
  \pgfmathparse{1/(#3*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((#1-#2)^2)/(2*#3^2))}%
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    no markers
  , domain=-3.2:3.2
  , samples=100
  , ymin=0
  , axis lines*=left
  , xlabel= $\textrm{X}$
  , every axis y label/.style={at=(current axis.above origin),anchor=south}
  , every axis x label/.style={at=(current axis.right of origin),anchor=west}
  , height=5cm
  , width=12cm
  , xtick=\empty
  , ytick=\empty
  , enlargelimits=false
  , clip=false
  , axis on top
  , grid = major
  , hide y axis
  ]

\draw [help lines] (axis cs:-3.5, -0.4) grid (axis cs:3.5, 0.5);

\addplot [cyan!50!black] {gauss(x, 0, 1)};
 \addplot [fill=cyan!20, draw=none, domain=-3:-1.96] {gauss(x, 0, 1)} \closedcycle;
 \addplot [fill=cyan!20, draw=none, domain=1.96:3.2] {gauss(x, 0, 1)} \closedcycle;


\draw[snake=ticks, segment length=1cm] (axis cs:-3.1, 0) -- (axis cs:3.1, 0);

\node[below] at (axis cs:-2, -0.02)  {$\overline{\textrm{X}} - 2\textrm{S}$}; 
\node[below] at (axis cs:-1, -0.02)  {$\overline{\textrm{X}} - \textrm{S}$}; 
\node[below] at (axis cs:0, -0.02)  {$\overline{\textrm{X}}$}; 
\node[below] at (axis cs:1, -0.02)  {$\overline{\textrm{X}} + \textrm{S}$}; 
\node[below] at (axis cs:2, -0.02)  {$\overline{\textrm{X}} + 2\textrm{S}$}; 

\draw (axis cs:-3.2, -0.15) --(axis cs:3.2, -0.15) ;
\node[right] at (axis cs:3.2, -0.15) {$\textrm{Z}$};
\draw[snake=ticks, segment length=1cm] (axis cs:-3.1, -0.15) -- (axis cs:3.1, -0.15);

\node[below] at (axis cs:-2, -0.16)  {$-2$}; 
\node[below] at (axis cs:-1, -0.16)  {$-1$}; 
\node[below] at (axis cs:0, -0.16)  {$0$}; 
\node[below] at (axis cs:1, -0.16)  {$1$}; 
\node[below] at (axis cs:2, -0.16)  {$2$}; 

\end{axis}


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you also explain what snake ticks are ? `snake` decoration is obsolete and needs to be used with `decorations.pathmorphing` if I'm understanding it correctly.

Comment: @percusse Maybe the `ticks` decoration of the `decorations.pathmorphing` library that probably was `snake=ticks` in older versions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There might be other solutions to this problem. However, here is my brute force solution.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{3}{%
  \pgfmathparse{1/(#3*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((#1-#2)^2)/(2*#3^2))}%
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    no markers
  , domain=-3.2:3.2
  , samples=100
  , ymin=0
  , axis lines*=left
  , xlabel= 
   , every axis y label/.style={at=(current axis.above origin),anchor=south}
  , every axis x label/.style={at=(current axis.right of origin),anchor=west}
  , height=5cm
  , width=12cm
  , xtick=\empty
  , ytick=\empty
  , enlargelimits=false
  , clip=false
  , axis on top
  , grid = major
  , hide y axis
  ]



%\draw [help lines] (axis cs:-3.5, -0.4) grid (axis cs:3.5, 0.5);

\addplot [cyan!50!black] {gauss(x, 0, 1)};
\pgfmathsetmacro\valueA{gauss(1, 0, 1)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\valueB{gauss(2, 0, 1)}

\node[right] at (axis cs:3.4, 0) {$\textrm{X}$};

\draw [dashed] (axis cs:1, 0) -- (axis cs:1, \valueA)
      (axis cs:-1, 0) -- (axis cs:-1, \valueA);

\draw [dashed] (axis cs:2, 0) -- (axis cs:2, \valueB)
    (axis cs:-2, 0) -- (axis cs:-2, \valueB);

\draw [latex-latex](axis cs:-1, 0.15) -- node [fill=white] {\footnotesize $68.27\%$} (axis cs:1, 0.15);
\draw [latex-latex](axis cs:-2, 0.03) -- node [fill=white] {\footnotesize $95.45\%$} (axis cs:2, 0.03);


\node[below] at (axis cs:-3, -0.02)  {$\overline{\textrm{X}} - 3\textrm{S}$}; 
\node[below] at (axis cs:-2, -0.02)  {$\overline{\textrm{X}} - 2\textrm{S}$}; 
\node[below] at (axis cs:-1, -0.02)  {$\overline{\textrm{X}} - \textrm{S}$}; 
\node[below] at (axis cs:0, -0.02)  {$\overline{\textrm{X}} $}; 
\node[below] at (axis cs:1, -0.02)  {$\overline{\textrm{X}} + \textrm{S}$}; 
\node[below] at (axis cs:2, -0.02)  {$\overline{\textrm{X}} + 2\textrm{S}$}; 
\node[below] at (axis cs:3, -0.02)  {$\overline{\textrm{X}} + 3\textrm{S}$}; 

\draw (axis cs:-3.2, -0.15) --(axis cs:3.2, -0.15) ;
\node[right] at (axis cs:3.4, -0.15) {$\textrm{Z}$};

\draw[thick] (axis cs:-3.0, -0.01) -- (axis cs:-3.0, 0.01);
\draw[thick] (axis cs:-2.0, -0.01) -- (axis cs:-2.0, 0.01);
\draw[thick] (axis cs:-1.0, -0.01) -- (axis cs:-1.0, 0.01);
\draw[thick] (axis cs:-0.0, -0.01) -- (axis cs:0.0, 0.01);
\draw[thick] (axis cs:1.0, -0.01) -- (axis cs:1.0, 0.01);
\draw[thick] (axis cs:2.0, -0.01) -- (axis cs:2.0, 0.01);
\draw[thick] (axis cs:3.0, -0.01) -- (axis cs:3.0, 0.01);




\node[below] at (axis cs:-2, -0.16)  {$-2$}; 
\node[below] at (axis cs:-3, -0.16)  {$-3$}; 
\node[below] at (axis cs:-1, -0.16)  {$-1$}; 
\node[below] at (axis cs:0, -0.16)  {$0$}; 
\node[below] at (axis cs:1, -0.16)  {$1$}; 
\node[below] at (axis cs:2, -0.16)  {$2$}; 
\node[below] at (axis cs:3, -0.16)  {$3$}; 

\draw[thick] (axis cs:-3.0, -0.16) -- (axis cs:-3.0, -0.14);
\draw[thick] (axis cs:-2.0, -0.16) -- (axis cs:-2.0, -0.14);
\draw[thick] (axis cs:-1.0, -0.16) -- (axis cs:-1.0, -0.14);
\draw[thick] (axis cs:-0.0, -0.16) -- (axis cs:0.0, -0.14);
\draw[thick] (axis cs:1.0, -0.16) -- (axis cs:1.0, -0.14);
\draw[thick] (axis cs:2.0, -0.16) -- (axis cs:2.0, -0.14);
\draw[thick] (axis cs:3.0, -0.16) -- (axis cs:3.0, -0.14);

\end{axis}


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]